# What is the logic of counting SWR answer with zero upvotes towards the total needed for a badge?

Tags: discussion

I just noticed that I am closing in on a gold badge for SWR.

I don't understand the logic of counting an answer which has zero or (zero net) votes towards the goal of 200 SWRs answered.  I would have thought an answer should have at least a +1 (or net +1) score.  Can anyone explain the logic?

Theoretically, one could have lots of bad (downvoted) answers offset by several very highly upvoted answers.  I'm not complaining, but it doesn't seem right to me.

Answer (score 7):

There is a points aspect to tag badges, as well as sheer number of answers.

[image: Gold badge description]

You must have a total score of 1000 in at least 200 non-community-wiki answers  to achieve a Gold badge. The questions you answer must be tagged correctly before you answer them.

So an answer which is not upvoted doesn't contribute to the necessary vote score, and a downvoted answer actually moves you further away from it. There is a reputation element to the badge.

Comment: Unless I misunderstood this answer, "score" is not the same as "reputation". In SE context, it's what shown on the post directly as the difference between upvote & downvote, so one upvote counteracts only one downvote for badge progression.

Comment: Yes. I have 226 answers in [single-word-requests] which have scored an aggregate of 1768 net upvotes. There have been some downvotes, so I guess I've gained over 15k rep from that tag. Let's edit the answer...